# Arrow pointing to the correct direction when click expan/collapse all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, expander

I did the "expand/collapse all" function, everything is working well, except the arrow. It doesn't pointing to the correct direction. I'm not sure how to do that, so I leave it empty on my code. My issue is shown below.

*(Red box represents the click action)*

1. Click "View all", can see the expanders are opened. The arrows pointing down.
   [image]
2. Click "A" to collapse the expander, and the arrow pointing up.
   [image]
3. Click "Collapse all", the expanders are collpased. Now you can see my problem, "A" arrow is pointing up and the rest are pointing down.
   [image]

Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(".aq_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".aq_epdtitle1").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".aq_epdtitle2").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".expandall").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
});

$(".collapseall").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideUp().removeClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideUp().removeClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideUp().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding: 0; } 


.eservices_left ul li{display:inline;}
.aq_expandct, .aq_expandct1, .aq_expandct2 {
 display: none;
 padding : 5px;
}
 
.aq_epdtitle, .aq_epdtitle1, .aq_epdtitle2{
 background:#ccc url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
 background-position:right 0px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
 
.collapsed .aq_epdtitle, .collapsed .aq_epdtitle1, .collapsed .aq_epdtitle2{
 background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandall">View all</div>
<div class="collapseall">Collapse all</div>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle">A</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct">
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle1">B</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct1">
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed noborder">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle2">C</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct2">
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it works fine on my machine...the arrow point up when expand and points down when collapsed

Comment: `view all` is not working fine either, because it inverses the arrows. Try to open manually one, and click on `view all`: the one you opened will show wrong arrow

Comment: @Kaddath you are right. Thanks for your explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `$('.mobexpand').addClass('collapsed');` (`$(".expandall").click`) in show all function

and `$('.mobexpand').removeClass('collapsed');` (`$(".collapseall").click`) and in collsapse all function as bellow

```js
$(".aq_epdtitle").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".aq_epdtitle1").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".aq_epdtitle2").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
  $(this).closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".expandall").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideDown().toggleClass('active');
  $('.mobexpand').removeClass('collapsed');
});

$(".collapseall").click(function() {
  $('.aq_expandct').slideUp().removeClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct1').slideUp().removeClass('active');
  $('.aq_expandct2').slideUp().removeClass('active');
  $('.mobexpand').addClass('collapsed');
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding: 0; } 


.eservices_left ul li{display:inline;}
.aq_expandct, .aq_expandct1, .aq_expandct2 {
 display: none;
 padding : 5px;
}
 
.aq_epdtitle, .aq_epdtitle1, .aq_epdtitle2{
 background:#ccc url('https://image.ibb.co/jUyN5Q/arrow_up_grey.png') no-repeat;
 background-position:right 0px;
 cursor:pointer;
 padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
 
.collapsed .aq_epdtitle, .collapsed .aq_epdtitle1, .collapsed .aq_epdtitle2{
 background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/d669kQ/arrow_down_grey.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandall">View all</div>
<div class="collapseall">Collapse all</div>
<ul>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle">A</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct">
      <li>A1</li>
      <li>A2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle1">B</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct1">
      <li>B1</li>
      <li>B2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="mobexpand collapsed noborder">
    <div class="aq_epdtitle2">C</div>
    <ul class="aq_expandct2">
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh my, the answer is so simple. And I never think about that. I still trying `$('.aq_expandct').closest('.mobexpand').toggleClass('collapsed');` but not working well too. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Hi @bRIMOs, I just realized that you code has issue. When click "view all", the arrow didn't change direction. End up the arrows are pointing to wrong direction. Can you see that?

Comment: just for clarification , is this probleme in the snippet or in your project code !

Comment: @Eelyn , please is the problem in the snippet or in your project ? because its seems to work fine here , where is the probleme exactly .

Comment: Sorry, misunderstand. The problem is in the snippet. Before click, the arrows are pointing down. If you try to click `view all` button, the arrows are still pointing down.

Comment: Probably can check here, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdhhh3ok/). I have changed the arrow to other icons, to make it more clearer. The arrows is quite confusing.

Comment: Okey great , seems just inversed the icons , so just inverse the add remove class in the two events , see snipet please

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with me, never think about that. Lol. May be too tired as rushing the project now. Thanks so much!

Comment: never mind :D , take a rest  to be more productive :) ,

Comment: Thank you :) Will rest after finish the project, haha!